# Warning 000405 when trying to calculate field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I am trying to create a model but am getting hung up on my first step. I need to calculate an ID field from an FID field so that I can join it to another table based on the ID field. So I have a table:

```
FID  Shape     ID
0    Polyline  0
1    Polyline  0
2    Polyline  0
```

Through the calculation, I was hoping to get something like this:

```
FID  Shape     ID
0    Polyline  1
1    Polyline  2
2    Polyline  3
```

Easy expression: `[FID]+1`. When I run the calculation though, I get the error 000405: No records within table. Since there won't be any data in the table until I join it to the other table, I'm not sure what to do here. Even trying to create a new field and running the same calculation returns the same warning.

Comment: There won't be any data "joined" to the table but certainly there is data in the first table (the shapefile) or else there is nothing to join to. The FID field is presumably a shapefile. Does it not have any features/records by itself?

Comment: A screenshot of the table you're trying to calculate in may help troubleshoot. Also, is this ArcMap or another GIS package?

Comment: I'm not understanding the "since there won't be any data in the table until I join it to the other table" part.

Comment: I agree with @GISKid... it sounds like you're trying to join a table to a blank shapefile.

Comment: As I understand the question, the 000405 error is coming up when trying to calculate a field in ModelBuilder (before the join) -- but I'm not sure, and hope to see clarification...

Comment: This problem is currently not reproducible.  Could you please supply more details so that people might be able to reproduce the problem (e.g. a screenshot of the model)?  Thanks.

Comment: Try to set geoprocessing extent to Union of inputs and re-run the model

Comment: Is the field you are calculating a numeric field? The [FID]+1 calculation you have described sounds to me like it "should" work.